# Delete duplicate data in SQL preserving the oldest entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a database that looks like the following

```
Col1    Col2
------------
0010    1111   (Delete this row)
0011    1112
0012    1111   (Keep this row)
```

I need to delete the duplicate data row found in Col2 based on Col1. I need to preserve the older entry and delete the younger. In this example I need to delete 0010 and keep 0012.

So far I have this code which shows me the duplicates in Col2 and shows the unique number from Col1

```
Select *
    From [database]
    Where (Col2) in (
        Select Col2
        From [database]
        Group by Col2
        Having Count(*) > 1
    )
```

I'm not wrapping my head around what I need to do next to select the correct Col1 number so I can delete that row.

Comment: What determines the Oldest  ... the sequence in Col1?

Comment: "I need to preserve the older entry and delete the younger. In this example I need to delete 0010 and keep 0012."  Assuming Col1 is a sequence/autonumber... wouldn't 0010 be the oldest and you want to keep the newest then?

Comment: Yes. Col1 never has any duplicate data and always increments by 1 for every new row added.

Comment: @Polarbehr please don't add "SOLVED" (or any other "tags") to your title. The site knows it's solved because you accepted (ticked) an answer - questions with an accepted answer already have a different appearance in the list. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (col1 varchar(25),col2 varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('0010','1111'),
('0011','1112'),
('0012','1111')

;with cteBase as (
    Select *,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By Col2 Order By Col1 Desc) from @YourTable
)
Select * From cteBase where RowNr>1
-- Delete From cteBase where RowNr>1
-- Remove Select if satisfied with results
```

Record(s) to be Deleted

```
col1    col2    RowNr
0010    1111    2
```

Comment: John that worked perfect! Thank you very much. Now I'm off to fix my files and then learn what you have shown me.

Comment: @Polarbehr  Get comfortable with the window functions.   They are invaluable.   Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte as
(
    -- oldest record will always have rn = 1
    SELECT Col1, Col2,
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Col2 ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS rn
    FROM YourTable
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
delete from [database] d1
    where exists (select 1 
                  from [database] d2
                  where d2.col2 =d1.col2 and d2.col1>d1.col1)
```